# Splitting and Trimming Columns in Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Spreadsheet modification web application and currently have a column of values formatted like so "#, name" and I need to programmatically split the # and the name into separate columns using Google Scripts. The results are coming from Forms, which is why they need modified. I have it partially working but I'm stuck on how to get it to fully work. Here is what I am doing so far:

```
output = splitColumn(initialRange.getValues()); //Initial range is the column I"m working with
      m = 0;
      var ids= [];
      var names= [];
      for(k = 0; k <= output.length; k+=2)
      {
        ids[m] = output[k][0];
        m += 1;
      }
      m=0;
      for(n = 1; n < output.length; n+=2)
      {
        names[m] = output[n][0];
        m += 1;
      }

      schoolName = aSheet.getRange(2, i+2, aSheet.getLastRow());
      schoolName.setValue(names[0]);
      schoolIDs = aSheet.getRange(2, i+1, aSheet.getLastRow());
      schoolIDs.setValue(ids[0]);
```

...

```
function splitColumn(range) {
  var output = [];

  for(var i in range) {
    var split = range[i][0].split(",");
    if(split.length == 1) {
      output.push([split[0]]);
    } else {
      for(var j in split) {
        output.push([split[j]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;  
}
```

To see my overall objective, these two screenshots should show it.

Original Spreadsheet from Form:
[image: Original]
Formatted Version of Spreadsheet:
[image: Formatted Version]

Either a modification to my existing code to make it work or suggesting a different approach would be appreciated. Current problems are actually setting the values, as it doesn't like the type I am using, and that the split does not get rid of the preceding white space between the "," and the "name" so my array has [space]name otherpartofname.

Comment: You can use `Logger.log('my variable value: ' + varName)` to print variable values to the LOG, then VIEW the LOG.  Put the Logger.log() in key places to verify that you are getting the expected results.

Comment: If the Google Form format is settled and this is the only wrangling you need to do, then you can do these manipulations direct in the form results sheet with no need to use Apps Script at all.

Comment: Right, I knew how to do those manipulations within the sheet. Thing is we are modifying 8+ different sheets and doing more than just this modification to it, so we decided a full web app with a few functions that do what we need would be best. Your statement is true though.

Comment: Obviously the snippets we see on SO never tell the full story, but I ask only because i see overuse of GAS and VBA in place of straightforward formula work all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this but modifying your existing code, you can `split()` using strings of more than single characters. Whatever you use is omitted.

```
var split = range[i][0].split(', '); // including space
// ['10', 'Africa High School'] — no white space
```

Other options would be regular expressions with matched groups like `/(\d{1,2}),\s([A-Z\s])` but is overkill here but a good thing to learn about if this becomes a work pattern more frequently.

Comment: It's the little things I guess. I had tried to do that type of thing within a spreadsheet program before and it took away all of my spaces making it like 'AfricaHighSchool'. However, it seems that this works nicely when using google scripts/javascript. Also, I was looking at regular expressions to solve it, but thought there had to be an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: If you are in full control of the input data then you can apply whatever method represents your level of confidence in the rules being applied consistently. In this case split works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.trim` to remove whitespace on both ends of a string.

[Mozilla Documentation - trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```
var numberToPush = split[0];
var trimmedNumber = numberToPush.trim();
output.push(trimmedNumber);
```

Comment: It seems that Google scripts does not recognize .trim() as a function. "TypeError: Cannot find function trim in object". So this would probably work in straight Javascript, but apparently not in Google scripts.

Comment: I changed the answer with more steps.  I did make a mistake in the former code.  `.trim()` will work in a `.gs` script file.  I had tried to use `.trim()` on an object, which won't work.  It only works on a string.